# live search opetion in codeigniter with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter. want to learn this. I am facing problem. data is not populated in search page.

in model

```
function fetch_data($query)
{
   $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('casedata');
        if($query!='')
        {
            $this->db->like('status',$query);

                }
                $this->db->order_by('SrNo','DESC');
                return $this->db->get();
    }
```

in controller the fetch function not getting data from database

```
    function fetch()
        {
             $output='';
            $query='';
            $this->load->model('crud_model');
            if ($this->input->post('query'));
            {
               $query= $this->input->post('query');
                            }
                            $data=$this->Crud_model->fetch_data($query);
                            $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table_bordered table-striped
                                <tr>
                                <th>SrNo.</th>
                                <th>Tile</th>
                            <th>File No.</th>
                            <th>Division</th>
                            <th>Section</th>
                            <th>LDH</th>
                         <th>NDH</th>
                            <th>PDH</th>
                            <th>STATUS</th>
                            </tr>';
                            if($data->num_rows()>0)
                            {
                                foreach($data->result() as $row)
                                {
                                    $output.='<tr> <td>'.$row->SrNo.'</td>
                                   $output.='<tr> <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->fileno.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->division.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->section.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->ldh.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->ndh.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->pdh.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->status.'</td></tr>';
                            }
                            }

                else{
                $output.='<tr> <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr> ';
            }
                $output.='</table>';
                echo $output;
             }
```

in view

```
  <html>       
    <body>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="panel panel-primary" data-collapsed="0">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title" >
                     <i class="entypo-plus-circled"></i>
                     <?php echo get_phrase('Search Data');?>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">                 
                  <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php? 
   admin/student/create/' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups- 
   bordered validate', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>      
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" 
    placeholder="Search by Customer Detsils" class="form-control"/>                
                     <div id="result">  
                     </div> 
                  </div> 
               </div>    
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()

    {

        load_data();

        function load_data(query)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php? 
     admin/fetch",method:"POST",
                data:{query:query},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            })
                  }
                  $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
                  var search=(this).val();
                  if (search!='')
                  {
                      load_data(search);
                  }
                  else
                  { load_data();
                  }
                  } );
       });
    </script>
```

Data is not populated in table. How to get output from this?

Comment: even the code hinting of stack doesn't know what to make of it. little tip: if you want people to help fix obvious errors.

Comment: if anyone solve my above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop throught the $data variable. please change the 'if' and 'foreach' as below code.

```
if(is_array($data) && count($data)>0)
   {
     foreach($data as $row)
    {
```

still if it not working try var_dump($data) and check whether results are coming or not.

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried above code. its not working also used var_dump($data) after foreach loop. its also can't work. please help me for this.

Comment: before do the var_dump($data) see if results are coming or not?